# How should I properly use setAttribute() method?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, rect, setattribute

I have a single svg element to which I'm adding a rect element with the createElement() method and then giving it its width and height with the setAttribute() method.

```
var svg = document.querySelector("svg");

function addRect(side) { 
  var newRect = document.createElement("rect"); 
  svg.appendChild(newRect);

  var thisRect = svg.lastChild;

  thisRect.setAttribute("width", side);
  thisRect.setAttribute("height", side);
}

addRect("100");
```

http://codepen.io/stromqvist/pen/YWZpNb

The result in chrome dev tools show `<rect width="100" height="100"></rect>`, yet the rect doesn't have any dimensions.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: createElement is wrong, use createElementNS and specify the SVG namespace as the first argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating SVG elements, you'd use createElementNS to create elements with a qualified namespace, like SVG elements

```
document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
```

and for certain attributes you'd use setAttributeNS, but for regular attributes like width and height, setAttribute should work

```
svg.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
```

[Demo click here](http://jsfiddle.net/5m5udg3v/)

Comment: Using createElementNS() method instead of createElement() method when creating the rect solved my problem. Thank you!